# Securing PDF Generated from iTextPdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, watermark

I have made a software that generate a pdf as the part of its function, I am using iTextPDF Java library to generate PDF. For a demo version of my software, I added text watermarking  (like "demo software") by use of following code

`PdfContentByte under = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
       BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
              under.beginText();
                        under.setColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                        under.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 25);
                        under.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER," demo software",250, 470,55);
                        under.endText();`

After it I converted it to .docx format using PDF to Word converter and the resultant docx file does not contain the watermark also the contents are easily editable so as a result the sole purpose of giving demo software is vanished.

How can I achieve permanent watermarking so that pdf to word converter wont be able to remove it.

One idea come to my mind is that instead of putting the text in the pdf there should be a way of converting all the text of a page first into an image then making the pdf comprising of those images. But I am unsure on how to achieve this using iTextPdf.

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt your `PDF` so that it cannot be modified without an owner password, after you have generated your `PDF`, create a `PDFStamper` with your `PDF` as input
and encrypt the pdf like the following:

```
final PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(your_input_stream);
final PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, your_output_stream);

stamper.setEncryption(PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA,
        "your_user_password", "your_owner_password", PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);

stamper.close();
```

As a side note, i would recommend not using a hardcoded owner password; since you have no need for the owner password after the file has been generated, I would suggest making it a `SHA` hash of a random string of say 20 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: is this possible to get the image of the text then making the pdf of it?

Comment: what do you mean?, is encrypting the document not possible for you?

Comment: encrypting wont help here as I can not put a password on the pdf file as it will result in every time when user wants to open the file he/she has to enter the password.
what i mean is..
suppose you have a pdf file of 2 pages. since the pages contains the  information as text so can I do a thing to convert the pages into Images and then making the pad of that images, so that now the pdf file has information in images taht can not be altered

Comment: If a user really wants to copy the text you can by no way stop them, even IF you convert the text to image, any OCR tool will be able to convert it to text again, regarding the password, if you just make the user_password `null` the user wont have to enter a password but the document will still be protected by the owner password, alas this can also be circumvented but it is better then nothing. basically any form of protection except DRM or certificates can be circumvented. hope this clears things up for you

Comment: @epoch even DRM and certificates can be circumvented by plain and simple screen capture + OCR. It just makes it harder, not impossible.

Comment: @epoch Hello, I am trying to encrypt after watermarking but unfortunately it gives me error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No valid encryption mode`.